# Symfony2 - Twig Exception after changing the name of a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem in Symfony 2.6.13.
I created a custom type GeneralBundle/Form/Type/DateRangeType.php:

```
<?php

namespace Ironstat\GeneralBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DateRangeType extends AbstractType
{
    const NAME = 'date_range';

    private $manager;

    public function __construct($manager) {
            $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dateFrom', 'date', array(
                'widget'        =>  'single_text',
                'format'        => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'datepicker input-small'),
                'label_attr'    => array('class' => 'control-label label-sm'),
                'label'     => 'Fecha desde',
                'empty_value'   => false,
            ))
            ->add('dateTo', 'date', array(
                'widget'        =>  'single_text',
                'format'        => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                'attr'      => array('class' => 'datepicker input-small'),
                'label_attr'    => array('class' => 'control-label label-sm'),
                'label'     => 'Fecha hasta',
                'empty_value'   => false
            ));

            $transformer = new DateRangeTransform($this->manager);

            $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ironstat\GeneralBundle\Entity\DateRange',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

So, as per the docs, i also create the service into GeneralBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    ironstat.type.date_range:
        class: Ironstat\GeneralBundle\Form\Type\DateRangeType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: date_range }
```

I also add into config.yml this configuration:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'IronstatGeneralBundle:Form:Type:DateRangeType'
```

But, when i try to add it in my form, i got this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Could not load type "date_range"") in
>   IronstatPacienteBundle:Page:edit.html.twig at line 27.

In my form, I'm adding it this way:

```
$builder->add('cau'     , 'collection'  , $this->getDateRangeType());
```

The last information that is important to know is that it stopped working after doing a **refactor** on the name of the bundle (yes, I'm a fool, i know...).
Before the refactor it worked fine. After doing the refactor (I changed *neostat* by *ironstat* in the whole project), everything works fine except that. I deleted the caches and regenerated the bootstrap.php.cache but it still does not work.
I also made sure to do the refactor well. The find of "Neostat" or "neostat" in the whole project does not bring me results.

What is missing?

Thanks a lot.

---

UPDATE: this is my appKernel.php:

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Ironstat\PacienteBundle\IronstatPacienteBundle(),
            new Ironstat\DiagnosticoBundle\IronstatDiagnosticoBundle(),
            new Ironstat\EntidadBundle\IronstatEntidadBundle(),
            new Ironstat\usuarioBundle\IronstatusuarioBundle(),
            new Ironstat\GeneralBundle\IronstatGeneralBundle(),
            new Siphoc\PdfBundle\SiphocPdfBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Ironstat\EnvioBundle\IronstatEnvioBundle(),
            new Ironstat\ArchivoBundle\IronstatArchivoBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new Ironstat\ReporteBundle\IronstatReporteBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
        );
```

And this is the getDateRangeType function:

```
private function getDateRangeType() {
        return array(
            'type'      => 'date_range',
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'attr'      => array('class' => 'datepicker input-small'),
            'label_attr'    => array('class' => 'control-label'),
            'empty_data'    => null
            );
    }
```

Comment: Did you adjust the auto-loader?

Comment: Yes, i regenerated it. It was a good attempt, but still fails...

Comment: show AppKernel for this bundle

Comment: What does your `$this->getDateRangeType()` function look like?

Comment: Yes, im sorry. I updated my post adding the registerBundles function in the AppKernel.php and the getDateRangeType function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
The problem was that it was missing renaming files (the refactor was not so well done, lol).
Apparently, I needed to rename the bundle configuration files. 
I noticed that when I ran this command console:

```
find ./ -name "Neostat*"
```

and file list was:

> ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/ReporteBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatReporteExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/usuarioBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatusuarioExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/ArchivoBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatArchivoExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/PacienteBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatPacienteExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/DiagnosticoBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatDiagnosticoExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/archivoBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatarchivoExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/envioBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatenvioExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/EnvioBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatEnvioExtension.php
>   ./Symfony/src/Ironstat/EntidadBundle/DependencyInjection/NeostatEntidadExtension.php

Changing the name of those files works.

Thanks a lot.